# How do I import csv data from a web download link to Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I use the same code (below) in many files to import data from a company website using a download link in my VBA code. But one particular URL will not work and gives me Run-time error '5' (Invalid procedure call or argument). I have narrowed it down to the dates in the connection string (Mon%20Jan%2003%202022). Is there any code that I can change to accommodate the dates into the download URL?

```
Sub ICE_ByNames_Extract()
'
' ICE_ByNames_Extract Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A:Z").ClearContents

Sheets("Output").Select
    
Dim ConnString As String

ConnString = "TEXT;" & "https://ice-core.pcf-phx.apps.boeing.com/api/ManagerStartup/Csv?fromDate=Mon%20Jan%2003%202022&toDate=Sun%20Mar%2020%202022&page=ByNames&rework=&program=CH-47%20ALL&shop=FLIGHT%20TEST&workcenter=&manager=&endItem=M%3A7603&status=&bemsId=3219547&variantId=null&programId=-1&majorProgram=CH-47"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ConnString, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Cells(1, 1))
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh
   
    End With
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to perform the above manually via browser and use the network tab of browser to monitor what happens. That might give you a starting point for getting the connection string right.